# Error while File upload using Jersey+Jquery+Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, rest, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

Here is my jQuery code.

```
  `$.ajax({
        url : '/RESTFULFileUPLOAD/rest/file/upload', //Server script to process data
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
        dataType : 'application/json',
        processData : false,
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var userObj = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
            alert(userObj);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);

        }
    });`
```

My Java code

```
       `@Path("/file")
        public class UploadFileService {

             @POST
            @Path("/upload")
            @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
             }
             }`
```

I am getting null pointer exception as a result.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.unquoteMediaTypeParameters(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:227)
com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:154) 
com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is a Javascript limitation on uploading files due to security.  try http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is solved,Actually i was getting wrong data in    **data : formData,**